# How to access to physical memory address in arm?

Tags: operating-system, arm

[image: friendly arm tiny4412 memory map]

For example, without mmu, leds are fixed at 0x110002E0, I can write values to this physical address to configure it. 
Here is question:

1. Where are these values written to, leds' register or dram?
2. If they are written to leds'registers, what physical address I should write to, so that the values can be written to the same address in dram?

Comment: Your questions don't make sense.  You can only write to one physical location at a time.  DRAM and leds are never written at the same place.  You may map two virtual addresses to one physical address, but you can never make one virtual address write to multiple physical addresses.  On ARM, all peripherals are memory mapped.  You need an entry in the MMU table to map to the physical location of the leds.  So the led register could be anywhere your system likes to map it.  If you meant you have no MMU, please say it.  DRAM works poorly without an MMU enabled so set a phys==virt L1 section map.

Comment: @artless noise, to make it not too complex, just talk about it with mmu disabled. dram can also be regarded as a peripheral, but dram has a very big size. I want to write a value to 0x110002E0 at dram, what physical address I should write to, 0x4000000 + 0x110002E0(dmc_base + offset) or just 0x110002E0?

Comment: The physical address is just as documented (0x110002E0); I don't know why you think you need to add the DRAM to the address.  Your module may require a clock enable to start it up.  So your writes won't do anything until the module is clocked.  You also may need to configure pins for the GPIO feature.  It may default to MMC or something.